# How to require input_field_2 if input_field_1 exist in database in spring mvc?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, spring-mvc

In the database I have a table of items.

The table contains the `item_number`, `item_name`, `item_desc`, ... and `require_item_number`

I have a page of receiving an item.

The user will be asked to input all the necessary information of the item that will be received. An input field for the `item_number`, `item_desc`, etc.

My problem is how will I make the input field required for the `item_number` if the `require_item_number` is true? else if the `require_item_number` is false the input field for the `item_number` will not be required.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by making a request to the server when the page is loaded to see if require_item_number is true or false.

P.S. Maybe I have not understood the question right. If you are asking how to make the field required just add a check when sending the information if the field should be required and if required, if is filled.